# Serving Assets on 'static' subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

How can I configure rails to serve assets on different subdomain? I basically want view/assets helpers to use subdomain for all static files, such as;

- instead of example.com/application.css -> static.example.com/application.css
- instead of example.com/application.js -> static.example.com/application.js
- instead of example.com/logo.jpg -> static.example.com/logo.jpg

Comment: can you tell us why would you want to do such thing?

Comment: I want to use a different machine to serve static files.

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons to do this; it's a common pattern.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

do you know about the `asset_host` option?

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "static.example.com"
```

it's also possible to do dynamic names:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  "http://assets#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(source).to_i(16) % 2 + 1}.example.com"
}
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Comment: Perfect, so i was not the only one trying to do that.

Comment: no, it's somesthing that you typically do in large-scale web-applications

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the `rack-cors` gem for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

I've used this gem in a Rails 4 app when my font-awesome icons wouldn't render once I started using subdomains. This wiki put me on the right path: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/wiki/CORS-Cross-Domain-Support

Besides modifying my Gemfile, I also put the following code into `config/application.rb` toward the top according to this guide: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/examples/rails4/config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors", :debug => true, :logger => (-> { Rails.logger }) do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '/cors',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:post],
      :max_age => 0

    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :patch, :options, :head],
      :max_age => 0
  end
end
```

Comment: How did you handle it in production? I mean did you configure Nginx or Apache too. I think this works well for assets when they are served through rails, but when its compiled we will have to configure Nginx for the job